Можно ли выговор получить?
Выговор выносят, дают, объявляют... А с другой стороны? Его получают?
Корректно ли будет так сказать?

Корректно. Выговор можно и получить.
Представители Справочного бюро на Грамоте.ру, отвечая на вопрос, употребляют именно "получить выговор":

